# Spring batch reader without specifying target class

Tags: spring-batch

I have a requirement where csv input file is dynamically created and hence specifying Mapper class is not possible.

Is there a way to avoid setting the class and still able to read and write in Spring batch

BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper();
fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(Target.class);//I want to avoid this.

Additional information :

1. Run some logic and create CSV(comma dilimited)
2. Columns are in order and I stored that information statically in properties file.(c1,c2,c3) which I also use to pass in lineTokenizer.setNames(properties.get(jobName.columnValues))
3. The same code executes for different jobNames and all information required is fetched from properties.
4. Now the problem : For FieldSetMapper
   Class classInstance = Class.forName(getClassProperty(jobName));
   fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(classInstance);
   for point 4 I have to maintain all the classes for each job which I want to avoid.
   Alternatively, the question is : I have a requirement where I am not sure how many fields will be in input file.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the statement 'csv input is dynamically created'?  By this do you mean that the content of the csv differs over a domain object (where the fields are fixed for every run of the Job but may be empty)? Or that the number and types of fields change on a Job to Job basis?

Comment: number and types of fields change on a Job to Job basis.

Comment: In that event, what is the intent of the job? Are you transforming the data and writing it out to a file? If so, does the file's format have a set of rules that it follows (e.g. pipe delimited, all numbers must be in a certain format, etc.)?

Comment: See Additional information : in the question I have updated.

Comment: For additional clarification - after you read in the file, what do you want to do with the data? Process it and write it to a file? Process it and write to a database table(s)?

Comment: You could take a look at the [ArrayFieldSetMapper](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/ArrayFieldSetMapper.html) class, which allows for the strings created by your LineTokenizer to backed by an array.  However you would then need to implement some logic to determine which tables in your database to write to if you were still adamant about keeping this as a single job and not maintaining multiple different backing beans.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it. Jobs have different beans, only reader writer are same and reused. write queries are picked from properties using jobName as well.